# nginx is not serving updated content

Tags: html, http, caching, nginx

When I pulled my changes to server, I am not getting updated changes.
My website is served through nginx.

```
location /areaboiadmin {
      root /opt/server/production/; 
}
```

I tried to clear my brwoser cache and still get the same response. I even used curl to fetch the resource and get the same old content. When I checked on the server, the files are updated.

What do you guys think is the problem?

I also turned **sendfile** option off and still same issue.

**Edit**

looks like sendfile options is working i forget to restart the server may be thats the problem

Comment: You will need to provide more information, most important, the **response headers** from the webserver to the client. Did you **verify** that the backend files on the server changed (timestamp of the files through `ls -al` for example) ?

Comment: Check twice that you access right server. Do you see your requests in nginx's log file?